# Creating basic file transfer between 2 applications on 2 computers using bluetooth in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, bluetooth, file-transfer

First,

- I don't want to pair the 2 computers manually.
- I don't want to use inbuilt bluetooth software to transfer file
- I don't won't windows to control my Bluetooth
- All done on Windows 7 computers
  (32Feet.net can be also applied if necessary)

I want to create two applications, say each knows of the other. Put them in two different computers and make them run. so each will turn on their Bluetooth antennas, and then the Two applications will connect using the bluetooth, and a file is sent from one to the other. thats really all.

How can I basically achieve this, can someone guide me?

Also I got 2 questions:

1. How can i set one application to broadcast a message that it exists over bluetooth.
2. How can the other detect this and connect to that computer using Bluetooth

One idea i have is to connect to each nearby computer iteratively and then search if the application exists, and then pair them automatically through the application itself (not by windows manually) and send the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my library 32feet.NET. :-)  To send the file use the class `ObexWebRequest` or for more advanced OBEX use see the partner library Brecham.Obex.  To discovery devices in range use `BluetoothClient.DiscoverDevices` or `BluetoothComponent.DiscoverDevicesAsync`. To respond to any authentication requests use class `BluetoothWin32Authentication`. :-)

See the user guide at [32feet.NET User Guide](http://32feet.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: Thanks I already went through the 32Feet.Net user guide few days ago. But my problem is, in order to use the suggested functionality the two computers must be paired right? How can I make this **pairing** automatic through C#. The 2 applications I create & run on the two machines should identify each other and establish the pairing. How can I achieve this? probably in C#. Thanks for the promptly reply.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that if both computer are on the same network. That you simply create a tcp listener on the receiving computer and send the file in byte array to it from the sending computer.

Comment: I want to use bluetooth and there is no other network connection.